# reading from a file and storing it in a structure(not properly reading the file)

Tags: c++, excel, vector, structure

The problem with my code is that in the while loop, the program is not properly reading the data in the file. If I were to output each individual member of the structure out of the while loop it would output stuff like zero, blank and even random numbers to different members of the structure. This also means that nothing is getting added to the vector because the vector size is zero.

Note 1-I'm using codeblocks as my IDE.

Note 2-The file that I'm using is an excel file. This means that I'm assuming that you've worked with excel files before and that you know that they're lined up in columns and rows. Also, I only want a certain amount of data going to each member in the structure.

Here's a very small sample from my input file.

```
EVENT_ID     CZ_NAME_STR    BEGIN_DATE  BEGIN_TIME
9991511      MIAMI-DADE CO. 10/18/1955  800
9991516      MIAMI-DADE CO. 4/10/1956   1730
9991517      MIAMI-DADE CO. 4/10/1956   1730
```

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Structure.
struct Weather_Event
{
  int eventID; // is the unique int id associated with the weather event.
  string CZ_NAME; // is the location associated with the weather event.
  char beginDate[11]; // is the date the event started.
  char beginTime[5]; // is the time the event started.
  string eventType; // is the type of weather event.
  int deaths; // are the number of people killed by the weather.
  int injuries; // are the number of people injured by the event.
  int propertyDamage; /* is the $ worth of property damage caused
                     by the event. */
  float beginLatitude; // is the starting latitude for the event.
  float beginLongitude; // is the starting longitude for the event.
};

int main()
{
// Create an empty vector that will contain the structure.
vector<Weather_Event>weatherInformation(0);

Weather_Event data; /* Create an object to access each member in
                       the structure. */

// Declare an object and open the file.
ifstream weather("weatherdata.csv");

if(!weather) // Check to see if the file opens.
    {
      cerr << "Error, opening file. ";
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // terminate the program early.
    }

/* While you're not at the end of the file, keep reading each new
   piece of data. */

while(weather >> data.eventID >> data.CZ_NAME >> data.beginDate
   >> data.beginTime >> data.eventType >> data.deaths
   >> data.injuries >> data.propertyDamage >> data.beginLatitude
   >> data.beginLongitude)
{
   /* Add all the data that was added to each member of the
    structure, into the vector. */
   weatherInformation.push_back(data);
}

weather.close();

// Next display the result
for(size_t i=0; i<weatherInformation.size(); i++)
{
   cout << "EventID: " << weatherInformation[i].eventID << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The very first call to `weather >> data.eventID` will fail, as the input file contains `EVENT_ID` at this point, which cannot be parsed as an integer. Once it fails, the `failbit` is set on the stream, and all subsequent calls will immediately fail, too. This is why the vector is empty - the condition in the while loop is false on the first iteration.

Comment: Once you get past that, realize that `weather >> data.CZ_NAME` will stop reading at the first whitespace character - in particular, a space between `MIAMI-DADE` and `CO.`

Comment: Please, before posting, search for similar or same posts.  For example, use the keywords "stackoverflow c++ read file structure".

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the format of the input doesn't seem to contain all the fields being read. That is, the input contains columns for event ID, name, begin data, and begin time but the code also reads event type, deaths, injuries, property damage, latitude, and longitude. Once this problem is address, you'll run into different other problems, though:

1. The first line doesn't match the format you are trying to read at all. You'll need to ignore it, e.g., using `weather.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`
2. The formatted input operator for string reads a single word. However, your name consists of multiple words, i.e., only the first of these words is read. I don't know if your file contains a suitable separators (e.g. tab characters `'\t'`) you could use to delimit the name or if the name as a fixed length or something. You'll need something to tell the stream where to stop reading the name.
3. When reading into a `char` array using the formatted input operators, you should set up a limit for the characters to be read to avoid an overflow: if you don't set up a limit, as many characters as matching the format will be read! That is, you want to read the `beginDate` and the `beginTime` using something like this:

   ```
   weather >> std::setw(sizeof(data.beginDate)) >> data.beginDate
           >> std::setw(sizeof(data.beginTime)) >> data.beginTime;
   ```

   Setting the width limits the amount of data being read. If there are more characters the input will fail rather than overflowing the buffer (if I recall correctly).

These are the problems I spotted based on the code and data you posted.

Comment: the reason I only showed those is because it's too long and I didn't want to drag it out. Sorry I should have explained that.

Comment: How could I check if my file has a suitable operator?

Comment: To do all of what you're asking, would it be better to do in a do while loop instead of a while loop. Also using weather.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); has caused my program to crash.

Comment: Never mind, it's not crashing anymore. I just placed it at the wrong location which was of outside of the while loop instead of placing it inside.

Comment: The `ignore()` needs to be done just once before entering the loop as it need to only skip over the first line. However, when you ignore the first line, the input of the event ID succeeds followed by a buffer overflow when reading the time unless you add the uses of `std::setw()` I advised: this overflow will crash your program, not the use of `ignore()`!

Comment: Whether you use a `while (...) { ... }` loop or a `do { ... } while (...)` loop doesn't matter. Note, however, that you need to make sure you check the stream stated *after* you have read the input before using the results.

Comment: When you ask about "operator" I assume you meant "separator": one simple way is to load the file into a text editor and see if adding characters cause the space to widen in jumps. If so, there is a tab character. If you have something which looks at the file displaying tab characters explicit (I'm using a UNIX which has a tool called `od` to do that) you should also see tab characters. Looking more closely at the question reveals that there are, indeed, tab characters. That is, you can read the name using, e.g., `std::getline(whether, data.CZ_NAME, '\t')`

Comment: Somebody here mention that the first line in the while loop, eventID and many other integer members, failed because you can't parse an integer. What should I do about that?

Comment: The comment wasn't that you can't parse an integer but that the first line starts out with a string which can't parsed as an integer! That's roughly the same statement I made: you need to skip the first line. Streams can certainly read integers but the stream will go into failure state if you give it some input which isn't an integer when trying to read an integer.